# What is an English phrase or idiom for an outsider suddenly taking control?

Tags: idiom-requests, politics

What is an English phrase or idiom with a **negative connotation** for *"an outsider, most probably a non-politician, suddenly comes from nowhere and takes control of a political situation because the real political players are less intelligent or less wise"*?

Please, realize that this is not a coup d’état.

I am translating something from my native language to English. My native language has a similar phrase: [উড়ে এসে জুড়ে বসা](https://bn.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A6%89%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A7%87_%E0%A6%8F%E0%A6%B8%E0%A7%87_%E0%A6%9C%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A7%87_%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BE).

I am looking for a verb, not a noun.

Comment: What is C2-level English? Standard dictionaries and grammars don't seem to include this designation.

Comment: @DW256, https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams-and-tests/proficiency/

Comment: Oh, in that case your question might be better on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site that caters to learners.

Comment: @DW256 C2 level is proficiency, it represents the level of a native speaker. Basically it's error-free speech, writing and listening, the exam is incredibly difficult

Comment: @Mari-LouA Perhaps the asker should have simply requested the word without mentioning a second language learner specific exam then. If special leaner-specific knowledge is required to answer the question, then it belongs on ELL which is, according to the help center, for "people who are learning or teaching English as a foreign language" not ELU which, according to the help center, is for "linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts", most of whom are likely neither familiar with, nor keen to become familiar with, whatever C2-level English is or is not.

Comment: There is an array of non-native speakers who participate on EL&U by asking and answering questions. I'm not saying this question is a good fit, or that it is particularly helpful to future visitors, I'm suggesting that @user366312 is free to participate here. Moreover, their question is far from being  basic or at beginner level.

Comment: Unfortunately, "demagogue" or "opportunist" may correspond both to an outsider or to an old parliamentary warhorse.

Comment: What is the source of the italicised definition? A verb that may fit the first part of it but not necessarily the second part is "usurp".

Comment: @Shoe, I am translating something from my native language to English. My native language has a similar phrase. https://bn.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A6%89%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A7%87_%E0%A6%8F%E0%A6%B8%E0%A7%87_%E0%A6%9C%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%A1%E0%A6%BC%E0%A7%87_%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BE

Comment: @shoe My thoughts exactly (and, as a disclaimer, I'm just very slow with writing answers, but started before you commented :).

Comment: The expression 'parachute in' ('He parachuted in'; often 'He was parachuted in') has the denotation but not the pejorative connotation. [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parachute)] // 'Muscle in' ('[phrasal verb]: to use your power to get involved in or take control of something that someone else was doing, especially in business – used to show disapproval') [[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/muscle-in)] includes the disapproval element, but is of course neither wiliness- nor politics-specific.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I believe *Parachute in* is a reference to the WWII coupe de main at Pegasus Bridge. But *coupe de main* doesn't verb well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are no verbs that completely carry that description, but the following one possibly come closest:

'[Usurp](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/usurp)':

> to seize and hold (a position, office, power, etc.) by force or without legal right:
> *The pretender tried to usurp the throne.*

Your description can be summarized by speaking of a ***foreign usurper*** (assuming a position of power is the kind of "political situation" you're talking about).

Comment: @user366312 As a noun, and based on what I was able to translate from the Bengali phrase you linked, "[opportunism](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/opportunism)" may come close, as well.

Answer (score 0):

A supplanter (noun) supplants (verb). In other words, he or she--through intrigue, underhanded tactics, force, scheming, or strategy takes the place of another. See https://www.thefreedictionary.com/supplant).

Jacob, one of the patriarchs of old, was the fraternal twin of his slightly older brother Esau. Though Esau, as the older, was entitled to the firstborn's portion of his father's inheritance, Jacob, through trickery and lying, received his father Isaac's blessing (see [Genesis Chapter 27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2027&version=NIV)).

Clearly, Jacob more than lived up to his name when he supplanted his older brother. The supplanting began at birth (see Genesis 25:26) and continued throughout his--and his brother Esau's--life.

> The Lord said to . . . [Rachel, when she was pregnant with Jacob and
> Esau:]
>
> “Two nations are in your womb,
> and two peoples from within you will be separated; one people will be stronger than the other,
> and the older will serve the younger.”
>
> When the time came for her to give birth, there were twin boys in her
> womb. The first to come out was red, and his whole body was like a
> hairy garment; so they named him Esau. After this, his brother came
> out, with his hand grasping Esau’s heel; so he was named Jacob.

Answer (score 0):

"They're taking over the reins"
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20the%20reins

In the sense of driving a Horse and Carriage

Or, to emphasise the fact that it's an outsider:
"They're muscling in"

As a metaphor for pushing in physically using shoulders
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muscle%20in

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).